# Dracula theme not recognized in init.vim

Tags: neovim, colorscheme, plugin-vim-plug

[Here is the tutorial I am trying to follow](https://medium.com/better-programming/setting-up-neovim-for-web-development-in-2020-d800de3efacd#:%7E:text=Editing%20the%20config%20file,vim%20.)

Here is the `init.vim` file I have written.

[image]

I just don't understand why I am getting the error

> Cannot find colorscheme 'dracula'

This error is occurring in the last line. Can someone please help me out? I am really stuck now.

I searched online a lot but couldn't find anything useful. I am working on WSL in windows 10. I don't have much knowledge about vim plugins. I have used vim only for basic c++ work earlier .

Comment: Did you do `PlugInstall`? (May be obvious but I gotta ask.)

Comment: No, I didn't , since colorscheme was not recognised, I thought its useless to run it.

Comment: Er, that command actually downloads and installs the colorscheme.

Comment: Thanks. I just ran it and yea it worked. I thought since its not recognized , it won't run .I didn't want my first question to be so stupid T_T

Comment: LOL. Don't worry about it! Not sure, though, whether I should actually post an answer for it. :)

Comment: Its upto you. U will have my upvote :)

Comment: :). Okay. I guess I might as well. Surely, you're not the first person to not realize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A brief word on how vim-plug works...

The main part of a plugin config is a path on GitHub. In your case `dracula/vim` refers to https://github.com/dracula/vim. What vim-plug needs to do, then, is download/install (using git) the plugin code from that address. But it doesn't happen automatically. It's up to you to run the command `:PlugInstall`. (And do so each time you add a new plugin(s).)

So once you've updated your vimrc just run `:PlugInstall` from an instance of Vim that sees the changed vimrc. You'll get some feedback on what happens from there.

Beyond installs there are a number of other commands related to maintaining plugins (`:PlugUpdate`, `:PlugClean`, etc.) that you'll need to keep in mind and run as needed. (The automatic part of vim-plug is primarily the management of runtime paths. The location of each configured plugin is added to that behind the scenes.)

Comment: Welcome to Vi&Vim SE, btw. :)